# Convert stock transactions into daily holdings in Excel

Tags: excel

interested in converting a transaction statement like so:

| Date (DD/MM/YY) | Stock | Flow |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 11/12/20 | Apple | 200 |
| 12/12/20 | Microsoft | 50 |
| 13/12/20 | Apple | -100 |

into something that looks like:

| Date (DD/MM/YY) | Apple | Microsoft |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10/12/20 | 0 | 0 |
| 11/12/20 | 200 | 0 |
| 12/12/20 | 200 | 50 |
| 13/12/20 | 100 | 50 |
| 14/12/20 | 100 | 50 |

Appreciate tips on the best way to go about doing so as I'm not quite sure how to approach this, thanks.

Comment: Use a database perhaps. To do something like this in Excel (assuming you have much more data) is to abuse it.

Comment: If you are going to use Excel, you can probably transform your data using Power Query. But you can do it fairly easily with formulas, also.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Formulas: (using O365) *slightly different approach may be needed in other versions*

*note that I created a table out of your stock flow data

```
F1: Date
G1: =TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(stockFlow[Stock]))
F2: =ROW(INDEX($A:$A,MIN(stockFlow[Date])-1):INDEX($A:$A,MAX(stockFlow[Date])+1))

G2: =SUMIFS(stockFlow[[Flow]:[Flow]],stockFlow[[Stock]:[Stock]],G$1,stockFlow[[Date]:[Date]],">="&$F$2,stockFlow[[Date]:[Date]],"<=" & $F2)
```

Select G2 and fill down and across as needed.

[image]

Comment: Awesome thank you so much, worked a charm and deals with missing dates which PivotTable wouldn't. Learned about tables today too.

Answer (score 0):

Use a Pivot table - create a pivot table, Make "Date" a row and "Stock" a column. Then make "Flow:" a value and change the "Value Field Settings" to "show values as" a "Running Total In..." with "Date" as the base field.

Note that the pivot table will not insert dates that aren't in your raw data, but you could insert rows for the missing dates with a zero flow for any stock to get the table you want:

[image]